# Javascript loop strings in between selected characters

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to create a for-loop with text content that I cannot modify. The text I am given looks like so:

`<start>John</stop><start>Billy</stop>`

I have two texts, `John` and `Billy` that are each surrounded by `start` and `stop` tags. What I would like to do is add these names without the tags to my HTML. My incomplete code looks something like:

```
var mytext = "<start>John</stop><start>Billy</stop>";
var count = (mytext.match(/<start>/g) || []).length;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
something.innerHTML += eachname;
}
```

Would like to know how to complete this.

Comment: are you using jquery??

Comment: Remove the HTML tags using `.replace(/<.*?>/g, ' ')` and add the resulting string in HTML page.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822452/2025923)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following javascript example for your solution.

```
var mytext = "<start>John</stop><start>Billy</stop>";
mytext = mytext.replace(/<\/?start[^>]*>/ig, ""); //Replace all <start> with blank
console.log(mytext.split(/<\/?stop[^>]*>/ig)); //Split by <stop> this may return an array ...
```

Comment: thanks! i chose this answer because it gave me the response as an array, which I should have clarified that's how I wanted it.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `/<[^>]*>/gi` like the following:

**Please Note:** Since the output is plain text it is better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

```js
var mytext = "<start>John</stop><start>Billy</stop>";

function get_content() {
     //var html = document.getElementById("txtInput").innerHTML;
     document.getElementById("txt").textContent = mytext.replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, "");
}
get_content();
```

```html
<div id="txt">
</div>
```

Comment: As you have HTML, why not just use `textContent`? Point is, OP have string, not HTML element inside DOM.